# Query to fetch friend matching a document reference from firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the Users data that I have

```
->firstName
->lastName
->uid
->grade
->friends[<Document Reference UID>] eg: [users/1, users/2, etc]
```

Now I want to fetch a list of uid where uid '1' exists

```
String userid="1";
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).get();
var friends = await users
      .where('friends', 'array-contains', userRef)
      .limit(3)
      .get();
```

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you run that code? If it doesn't work (in which case, please specify the way in which it doesn't work), have you checked whether that's actually related to Cloud Functions? Does the same code work if you just run it locally? It's unclear to me how Cloud Functions is relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).get();
```

Your `userRef` value is not a `DocumentReference`, but is actually a `Promise<DocumentSnapshot>`. And that won't work in the subsequent `.where('friends', 'array-contains', userRef)` condition - as there won't be any documents matching that type.

---

What you want is:

```
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userid);
```

So without `.get()` at the end. Now `userRef` contains a `DocumentReference`, which will match documents that have that same document reference in the `friends` array.